# How to open separate tooltip with same class in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

i am learning JQuery and for this i did this work. I am facing problem when i mouse hover on thumbnail all tool tip is opening, i wanted to open only related tooltip, I don't want to use multiple classes for this i want to do this work with same classes. Is there any way to do this work with out taking separate classes for every thumbnail?

Here is the link: http://shahfahad.com/jquery/hide-show.html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6Y3F.jpg)
check attached screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".model").css("display","none");  
        $(".hide").click(function(){
        $(".show").closest("ul").removeClass("showing");
        $(".model").hide();

    }); 

    $(".show").mouseover(function(){

        if(!$(this).closest("ul").hasClass("showing")){
        $(this).closest("ul").addClass("showing");
        $(this).next(".model").show(); 
        }
    });

});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/wfmef9os/)

Comment: feel free to ask

Answer (score 0):

but it has another issue , can it possible when one tooltip has opened and you mouse over on another thumbnail so two thumbnails will open at the same time , is it possible when mouse over on new thumbnail previous tooltip will close and then appear new tooltip?